# Visual Basic alternative for Ubuntu?

Tags: design

I used Visual Basic on Windows just to make the design of programs, no codding.
But I can't find any alternative despite Gambas and Mono :/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can install Visual Basic in linux1 via wine but why bother when you can use a native app instead? Gambas2 is a full-featured object language and development environment built on a BASIC interpreter.

According to its creator, Benoît Minisini, Gambas does not try to be compatible with Visual Basic. Instead, Gambas is an improvement over VB6. He claims that Gambas' syntax and internals are far better than that of VB6:

Gambas is a free development environment based on a Basic interpreter with object extensions, a bit like Visual Basic™ (but it is NOT a clone!).

Gambas includes an interpreter, a compiler, an archiver, and a graphical Integrated Development Environment or IDE.<sup>[Visual Basic Alternative in Linux](http://scriptogr.am/sirgain/post/visual-basic-alternative-in-linux)</sup>

To download Gambas, and more info check out the [website](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html).

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it is even in the repositories. And for the latest releases there is a ppa ppa:gambas-team/gambas-daily

Answer (score 0):

I think [Qt Designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) is the closest you can get on Linux.

Comment: hum I don't know :/ Seems much more complicated then vb

Comment: Yes, I know. GUI designing was always easier in Windows and most likely it always will be.